# ggplot2: line connecting the means of grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to group one variable of my data by another and then plot a line through the means. It works fine when both variables are numbers. However, I'm having a problem when the grouping variable is a factor. I have a mock up below.

```
x <- sample(1:3, 40, replace=T)
y <- rnorm(40)

df1 <- data.frame(x, y)
qplot(x, y, data=df1) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line")
```

[image]

This is looks great. However if the x variable is a factor I don't get the line.

```
df2 <- data.frame(x=as.factor(x), y)
qplot(x, y, data=df2) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line")
```

[image]

Is there something I can do to get this line displayed?

Ps. geom="point" works but not geom="line"

```
qplot(x, y, data=df2) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point")
```

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ggplot2` intentionally makes it a little tricky to draw lines across x-axis factors, because you need to make sure that it's meaningful. If your x-axis was "New York", "Philadelphia" and "Boston", it wouldn't be a good idea to draw a line connecting them.

However, assuming that your x variable has a meaningful order, you have to define the `group` aesthetic to draw the line you want. Here, `group = 1`.

```
qplot(x, y, data=df2) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))
```

If you just add `geom_line()` to a plot like this, you will have to define the grouping variable in a similar way.

Comment: These solutions no longer work. They generate the error: "geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: `ggplot(df2, aes(x=x), y=y)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", aes(group=factor(grouping)))` worked for me

Comment: @JoFrhwld, what if one has another variable `z` that classify the observations into two groups,  say `H` and `L`, and what to plot the mean line of each group in the same plot?

Comment: That's a great function [stats_summary]. I thought I'd need to manually calculate and draw the means.