# Approach for creating plotting means from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, mean

Trying to develop a flexible script to plot mean of continuous variable observations 'score' as a function of discrete time points 'day' from data frame.

I can do this by creating subsets, but I have a big set of data with many factor vectors like 'day,' so would like to get vectors or a data frame for each factor and its corresponding mean.

I have a data frame structured like this:

```
subject day score
      1   0 99.13
      2   0    NA
      3   0 86.87
      1   7 73.71
      2   7 82.42
      3   7 84.45
      1  14 66.88
      2  14 83.73
      3  14    NA
```

I tried tapply(), but couldn't get it to output vectors or tables with appropriate headers and could also handle NAs.

Looking for a simple bit of code to get two vectors or a data frame with which to plot mean of 'score' as a function of factor 'day'.

So the plot will have point for average score on each day 0, 7, and 14.

I have seen a lot of posts for doing this [directly with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039119/plotting-means-as-a-line-plot-onto-a-scatter-plot-with-ggplot), but it seems useful to know how to do, and I need to see the output to make sure it is handling NAs correctly.

*If you are able to help, please include explanatory annotations in your script. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

I think `tapply` should be able to handle this, you can amend the function to remove NAs:

```
df=data.frame("subject"=rep(1:3,3), "day"=as.factor(rep(c(0,7,14),each=3)),
              "score"=c(99.13,NA,86.87,73.71,82.42,84.45,66.88,83.73,NA))

res = with(df, tapply(score, day, function(x) mean(x,na.rm=T)))
```

#### EDIT to get day and score as vectors

```
day=as.numeric(names(res))
day
0  7 14

score=as.numeric(res)
score
93.00000 80.19333 75.30500
```

Plot in base R:

```
plot(x=as.numeric(as.character(df$day)),y=df$score,type="p")
lines(x=names(res),y=res, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: That solves the problem of NAs, but was looking for something that would output something with usable vectors or simple dataframe like:
`day    score                                                                                                    
    0      93.00                                                                                                   
    7      80.19                                                                                               
    14     75.31`

Comment: Well I can;t get the hang of mini-Markdown but a vector for day and vector for score.

Comment: OK, they are both held in `res`. I have edited the answer to extract them

Comment: Yep that worked well and seems nice sand straightforward. I guess I am not too familiar with this type of object which was the challenge perhaps. I anticipate it will work fine with factors not in order in the df because the two observations, mean score and day are paired.

Comment: That is correct @MasonK, the order will not affect the analysis. But if you wish to plot it as a line, you will have to reorder it first. Good luck!

Comment: Ok I see @mr_jaundo, thanks! Yeah, using that with a bigger data set I can have a neat data frame to inspect and QA means and standard deviations for a control and treatment, and easily plot said means and sd bars. Very nice.

Comment: Happy to help :) @MasonK

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what are you trying to achieve. Here I will show how to use the `ggplot2` package to create a point plot with the mean for each group. Assuming that `dt` is your data frame.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt, aes(x = day, y = score, color = factor(subject))) + # Specify x, y and color information
  geom_point(size = 3) +                                       # plot the point and specify the size is 3
  scale_color_brewer(name = "Subject", 
                     type = "qual", 
                     palette = "Pastel1") +                    # Format the color of points and the legend using ColorBrewer
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 7, 14)) +                   # Set the breaks on x-axis
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", 
               color = "red", 
               geom = "point", 
               size = 5, 
               shape = 8) +                                    # Compute mean of each group and plot it
  theme_classic()                                              # Specify the theme
```

> Warning messages: 1: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values
>   (stat_summary).  2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values
>   (geom_point).

If you run the above code, you will get the warning message and a plot as follows. The warning message means `NA` has been removed, so you don't need to further remove `NA` from the dataset.

[image]

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "subject day score
      1   0 99.13
                 2   0    NA
                 3   0 86.87
                 1   7 73.71
                 2   7 82.42
                 3   7 84.45
                 1  14 66.88
                 2  14 83.73
                 3  14    NA",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```