# How create a box plot + line plot in a single plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a box plot + line plot in a single plot using ggplot2

This is what my code now:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(day = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10,10,14,14,14,14,14,14,21,21,21,21,21,21,28,28,28,28,28,28,35,35,35,35,35,35,42,42,42,42,42,42), group = c('Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP'), score = c(37.5,43,7,63,26,15,17,16,43,26,53,26,26,26,43,10,6,15,18,9,10,4,8,18,60,26,20,12.5,9,43,43,43,11,10,7,60,43,43,32,10.5,8,57.5))


g1 = ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = factor(day), y = score)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = group))

g1
```

When doing box plot, I want scores of different treatments(groups) to be represented separately, so I let x = factor(day).
But for line plot, I want each day's score to be the average of the two treatments(group) of the day.

[This is how my plot look like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VOwi.png)

[This is how I want my plot to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lfd8.jpg)

How can I do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: please edit your question to include the data as code. Do not expect people to create the dataframe in R cell by cell from your image.

Comment: for example: `dat <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3), group = c(4,5,6))`

Comment: Hi and welcome @Jason to stack overflow. It seems that a simliar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039119/plotting-means-as-a-line-plot-onto-a-scatter-plot-with-ggplot . The solution could be something like `stat_summary(aes(group=1), fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line",group=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Libraries

library(tidyverse)

#Data

dat <- data.frame(day = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10,10,14,14,14,14,14,14,21,21,21,21,21,21,28,28,28,28,28,28,35,35,35,35,35,35,42,42,42,42,42,42), group = c('Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP','Saline','RP','Saline','Saline','RP','RP'), score = c(37.5,43,7,63,26,15,17,16,43,26,53,26,26,26,43,10,6,15,18,9,10,4,8,18,60,26,20,12.5,9,43,43,43,11,10,7,60,43,43,32,10.5,8,57.5))


#How to

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(day), y = score)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = group))+
  geom_line(
    data = dat %>% 
      group_by(day) %>% 
      summarise(score = median(score,na.rm = TRUE)),
    aes(group = 1),
    size = 1,
    col = "red"
  )
```

[image]